# Did Ace master any Haki abilities?

Tags: one-piece

Ace was the 2nd division commander of the Whitebeard crew, but he hadn't displayed power befitting of his title. Besides the fact that he was a Logia user with the power to control fire from Mera-Mera No Mi, he has not demonstrated any other type of powers like Haki.

For example:

- In the Alabasta Arc, he fought against Smoker, but he wasn't able to put up a good fight, claiming that both were Logia users and the fight would end with no result.

  <sup>This also raises questions about Smoker's Haki abilities and the fact that even Smoker wasn't able to use Haki at that time.</sup>
- He wasn't able to hit Blackbeard when Blackbeard used his Logia power.
- He showed no resistance when Akainu hit him, not even weak Haki, and took the hit head-on.

He never fought Logia users with Haki, nor has he shown remarkable Kenbunshoku Haki.

Haki was revealed after the time skip, but it has been there since Rayleigh's and Roger's times. Were Ace's abilities limited to his Devil Fruit power only?

Comment: As a short answer: It is actually very uncommon to have Haki, even in Paradise (begin of the Grandline). This changes drastically from the New World onwards as those without Haki die pretty fast there.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Ace had possessed Haoshoku Haki.

According to [Portgas D. Ace](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Portgas_D._Ace#Haki) article on One Piece Wiki:

> While not portrayed in the main storyline, it was revealed in a flashback that Ace possesses Haoshoku Haki, which at the time he had no conscious control over. Ace first demonstrated the ability at 10 years of age, when he knocked the Bluejam Pirates crew unconscious after an outburst of rage (only Bluejam himself remained conscious from the Haki release, and he was a high-tier of East Blue at the time). Much as Luffy used his Haki to knock out a crowd of Kuja warriors, Ace used his Haki to knock out the attacking members of Bluejam's pirate crew.
>
> Ace was first shown to have knowledge about it when during the Battle in Marineford, he witnessed Luffy unknowingly unleash his Haki and remarked "You too?". He has never been seen using Haki apart from during his childhood.

Ace unleashed Haoshoku Haki in chapter 587...

[image: Using Haki]

... and Bluejam's pirate crew after they are hit by Ace's Haki.

[image: After using haki]

He might have developed and mastered other types of Haki too, but they are not shown in the manga. After all, he was the 2nd division commander of the Whitebeard Pirates and had the power of D.

Comment: Using conqueror's Haki once is not enough proof for the presence of all three Haki abilities and there are rumors that that demonstration of Haki during childhood was by Dragon who was lurking in the shadows protecting Luffy and save him, like he did against Smoker. Also he has not shown Haki even if his life is at risk? That's unusual and hard to grasp.

Comment: It is enough just for once, actually every body possess Haki which is also call will power, it depends upon you activate it or not, there are condition where haki is activated, once activated you should train hard it to control and master it, check [here](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Haki) for more information about haki

Comment: Then why didn't he use it against Smoker, Blackbeard and Akainu?

Comment: for that you should ask another question , question answer in comment will not be good